# Java IXOR ~ [one side] equality refactoring question

Tags: java, refactoring, deobfuscation

```
public byte[] method(int var1)
{
        if(var1 == ~L.length) //<- this
            return a(i1, 0, false);
}
```

how would I go upon fixing

```
if(var1 == ~L.length)
```

to remove the `~`

must I change `==` to `!=` ?

```
if(var1 != L.length)
```

Thanks this is probably the last question of this type.

ps.>
Thanks for helping me out with the previous ones like

`~(-1 + var1) < -1` to `var1 > 1`

`~(var1 & 0x22) != -1` to `(var1 & 0x22) != 0`

`~var1 < ~var2` to `var1 > var2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I told you before, you can replace `~x` with `-x - 1`

So, `if(var1 == ~L.length)` is equivalent to `if(var1 == -L.length - 1)`

Comment: haha I hate seeing the same faces.. makes me seem like a bigger fool then ever.

Comment: if(var1 == -L.length - 1) seems more complicated

Comment: Then use `if(var1 + 1 == -L.length)`

Comment: Ohhhhhhh i finally got it always replace ~var with -var - 1 and keep working from there.

Answer (score 0):

If it's trying to do 2's complement tricks again:

```
-var1 == L.length + 1
```

or

```
var1 + 1 == -L.length
```

(Basically use the fact that `~x == -(x+1) == -x - 1`)

Another way to rewrite it is:

```
var1 ^ L.length == -1
```